# GitHub not loading "net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Tags: github, repository, github-pages

All css styles hosted on GitHub were lost and page looks broken. The GitHub site appears to be down and unable to access GitHub homepage.

I see error message:

```
Failed to load resource:
```

Is it GitHub or my internet?

Comment: http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my security team blocking GitHub.

(GitHub does not go down because of It's back-up servers)

Answer (score 0):

I just made a commitment today, all was fine. It was 2 hours ago though.